# Fail to execute JavaScript from HTML file - document not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I can't succeed in calling JavaScript file from a HTML file.

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script  src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'</script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js' </script>
    <script>theTest(); </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myTest" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
function theTest()
{
    var they = 2;
    console.log(they);
    alert(they);
};

document.getElementById('myTest').innerHTML;
```

I am receiving:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648001/479156).

Comment: @julekgwa:Sorry, what do you mean a typo?

Comment: @julekgwa - For future reference, no need to create your own closure option for that case. There's already a choice that cites "simple typographical error".

Comment: @Ivar:It then shows `window` is not defined.

Comment: Is the missing `>` in your jQuery `<script>` tag a typo here, or in your original code?

Comment: ^ Better yet, of the three `<script>` tags, only *one* is properly closed.

Comment: @freginold Both the jQuery and the test.js.

Comment: @Santi Good catch, I missed that one. @George, try closing those two `script` tags properly in your HTML file and see if your code works.

Comment: I closed the tags (sorry) but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `theTest();` before the browser is generating the `#myTest` element, or even starting to build the page, so the function has nothing to act on.  Move your third `script` tag down to the end of your `body` element, and it should work fine.  See this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myTest" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
    <script>
        theTest();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: H, thanks but I am still getting the error about document not found.Let me remind you that I want to call the javascript file which executes the html file and not the opposite.

Comment: But the function is not calling any page element.

Comment: @George Where are you loading the HTML file from your JavaScript file?

Comment: @freginold:I am trying to use the `document.getElementById('myTest').innerHTML;` for that.Sorry, I am not experienced in html and javascript.

Comment: @George That line of code does literally nothing. You're getting the HTML content of the `myTest` element, but you're not saving it, changing it, doing anything with it, etc. For example, `document.getElementById('myTest').innerHTML = "Hello world!"` would set the HTML. `var myHtml = document.getElementById('myTest').innerHTML;` would store it as a variable. But that line on it's own has no purpose.

Comment: @George To be clear, you're trying to have `test.js` load `test.html`?

Comment: @freginold:yes, exactly.and of course use any result from javascript file.

Comment: @George To load a new HTML page, you would do something like this: `window.location.href = "test.html";`

Comment: @freginold;It says `window` id not defined, like `document` is not defined.And I can't seem to find a solution1

Comment: @George What command are you running that is giving an "ID not defined" error for `window`?

Comment: @freginold:`node test.js`

Comment: @George If you're running this code in Node.js, that is completely different from running it in a web browser. Node.js does not have a `window` object. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33320084/5463636) for more detail.

Comment: @freginold:I see..So, there is no easy solution for this.You can't just launch an html file from javascript code.

Comment: @George It really depends on what you want to do. If you're using a Windows system and don't actually need a web browser, just a GUI, you could use an [HTA file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742317.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).